# How can I make a word cloud based on a condition in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, sentiment-analysis, word-cloud

i try to make a word cloud of the column "Review Gast" based on a condition that the column "sentiment" needs to be "negative". However the wordclouds shows all Reviews and not only the negative ones. What am I doing wrong?

```
for i in reviews_english[reviews_english['sentiment']=='negative']['Review Gast'].astype(str).values:
    vectorizerneg = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3, 3), stop_words=STOPWORDS and ['width', 'px', 'jpg', 'cdn', 'src', 'https'])
bag_of_words = vectorizerneg.fit_transform(reviews_english['Review Gast'])
vectorizer.vocabulary_
sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print (words_freq[:100])
#Generating wordcloud and saving as jpg image
words_dict = dict(words_freq)
WC_height = 1000
WC_width = 1500
WC_max_words = 200
wordCloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800,background_color="white",min_font_size = 10, max_words=50)
wordCloud.generate_from_frequencies(words_dict)
plt.title('Most frequently occurring bigrams connected by same colour and font size')
plt.imshow(wordCloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
wordCloud.to_file('wordcloud_bigram.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running `fit_transform` on the entire column `reviews_english['Review Gast']`. Try

```
vectorizerneg = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3, 3), stop_words=STOPWORDS and ['width', 'px', 'jpg', 'cdn', 'src', 'https'])
bag_of_words = vectorizerneg.fit_transform(reviews_english[reviews_english['sentiment']=='negative']['Review Gast'].to_list())
```

You can remove the for loop because it does nothing but reload CountVectorizer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However it does not work, the following error occures: "IndexError: index 71192 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 17507". Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: On which line in the code does it throw this error?

Comment: In this line:  8 words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]

Comment: Rename `vectorizer` in that line to `vectorizerneg`, otherwise your code is not consistent. There is probably another variable `vectorizer` in your code that you're erroneously loading on that line.